# Shared lib with link to static libs internally

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, static-linking

I have a shared library called **MyLib**. I have linked **MyLib** to a static version of Boost and three other libraries.

**MyLib** does not expose any feature of those linked libraries. In other words, the public interface headers of **MyLib** does not mention or include Boost or any other library.

I have built **MyLib** and got .lib(.a) and .dll(.so) files.

Now, I have **MyEXE** which is a program that is linked to **MyLib**. Everything is smooth till now.

If I need some feature of Boost or the other three libraries to be used in **MyEXE**:

- Will it be safe to link **MyEXE** to Boost or the other libraries? Will I face any ODR problem?
- If it is OK to link to them, should I link to the exact same version of Boost and other libraries that were used with **MyLIB**?
- Does the previous scenario seems bad? Should I follow a better scenario? (Distributing the source and keeping the link process to the end developer is not an option for me)